# Custom image attribute is not displayed on search list

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a custom media image attribute called `hover_image` as you may understand when a customer hovers on the product image `hover_image`  shows up.

This works with catalog list but when I search for a product the list that comes up does not show the image that I uploaded to hover_image. it shows placeholder that I uploaded for hover_image from `system>configuration>catalog`

this is the code that I use for displaying hover image in the `list.phtml` view

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400,600); ?>" width="300" height="400" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400,600) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400,600) ?>';" />
</a>
```

Comment: How did u added the attribute..

Comment: have you checked it in console whether that event updated in your search result page?